# Problem to make redeploy programmatically using JBoss 5.1

Tags: java, jboss, jboss5.x

I have a problem to make redeploy programmatically using JBoss 5.1. After starting JBoss the follow code works well. But after the first time that it execute always the program freeze at line with "problem here", without throwing any exception, and showing a message that was done undeploy from "project.sar" and nothing more.

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
ProfileService profile = (ProfileService) ctx.lookup("ProfileService");
DeploymentManager dm = profile.getDeploymentManager();

DeploymentProgress redeploy;

{
    try {
        System.out.println("Redeploy: "+dm.isRedeploySupported()); // show always true
        redeploy = dm.redeploy("project.sar");
        redeploy.run(); // problem here
        checkProgress(redeploy);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        ...
    }
}

ctx.close();
dm.releaseProfile();
```

Any idea about what's happening? Is this a bug from the version 5.1?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're not including that code in project.sar, do you?

Comment: @Thomas. No. This code is from another project, responsible for redeploy from another projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My conclusion is that problem is a bug from the version 5.1. I found others problems like this, such as [this](http://community.jboss.org/message/8038).